# How to report phishing in Teck Resources mail?

Tags: security, procedure

in a clear and well established way.I want a sequence of steps or actions to perform to notify phishing, dangerous or malicious emails.

Find in the documentation in confluence or through one of the Teck channels in teams, the way to report this type of emails for analysis and follow-up.